CSS subgrid, cells alignment
I try to align subgrid elements with each other.
I have extended my initial subgrid example (CSS Grid, unexpected gap) with more nested rows and I'm now facing alignment issues. The red and blue blocks are not aligned with each others. I've been playing with many different grid properties but there is definitely something I don't get about grids. Can someone help me again with this?


.cards {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            grid-column-gap: 10px;
        }
        
        .card {
            display: grid;
            grid-row-gap: 10px;
            grid-template-rows: subgrid;
            grid-row: span 3;
        }
        
        .header {
            background-color: orange;
        }
        
        
        .content {
            background-color: grey;
            display: grid;
        }
        
        .name {
            background-color: tomato;
        }
        
        .description {
            background-color: skyblue;
        }
        
        .footer {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
   <div class="cards">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 10%" />
            <div class="name">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
            <div class="description">Cras imperdiet erat ante. Suspendisse eget egestas felis. Cras justo sapien, venenatis et lectus vitae, finibus accumsan ex.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">Cras imperdiet erat ante. Suspendisse eget egestas felis. Cras justo sapien, venenatis et lectus vitae, finibus accumsan ex.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 15%" />
            <div class="name"></div>
            <div class="description"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 20%" />
            <div class="name">Lorem.</div>
            <div class="description">Cras imperdiet erat ante. Suspendisse eget egestas felis. Cras justo sapien, venenatis et lectus vitae, finibus accumsan ex. Cras imperdiet erat ante. Suspendisse eget egestas felis. Cras justo sapien, venenatis et lectus vitae, finibus accumsan ex.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header"> Cras imperdiet erat ante. Suspendisse eget egestas felis. Cras justo sapien, venenatis et lectus vitae, finibus accumsan ex.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 25%" />
            <div class="name"></div>
            <div class="description"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1220067947798024192/30eZhfxx_400x400.png" style="width: 30%" />
            <div class="name"></div>
            <div class="description"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>




You can set the something like  grid-auto-rows: 1fr 5fr; on your content and define the "various" div as display: grid; grid-auto-rows: 1fr 1fr; Btw in your first card > content there is no various div.

I removed the "various" div, it was there by mistake.

You could declare grid-template-rows: subgrid; also on .content. Then adjust the grid-row on .card to span 5 and on .content to span 3. Is this what you're looking for?
https://jsfiddle.net/o29g7yah/97/
